# How to check if an EXE is installed on windows by a web-page?

Tags: redirect, download, installation, exe

I want to create a web-page that will redirect to run an EXE if the EXE is installed. If the EXE is not installed on the PC, it will redirect to a download page .

My code to run the exe is:

```
document.location.href=' Myapp:// ';   
setTimeout("history.go(-1)",2000);
```

How can I check if the exe is installed on the PC?

Comment: If the browser allowed you to see what exe's I had on my system, I'd change browser :) The exe's installer could possibly register in the browser to add a header with that info, but that's a bit more involved than just seeing an exe in the file system.